# How to delay Java code untill another part of the code is finished?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent

so I was trying out the java.awt.Graphics library and came across an issue in my code. The code below returns a null pointer exception because the Graphics object "g" is not defined at the time of execution. I could loop the call and check if g != null but is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for any help.

This is my code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel{

Graphics g;

public Gui() 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.g = g;

    g.setColor(Color.blue);

    for(int x = 0;x < 700; x += 20) 
    {
        g.drawLine(x, 0, x, 700);
    }

    for(int y = 0;y < 700; y += 20) 
    {
        g.drawLine(0, y, 700, y);
    }
}

public void draw(Tuple xy) 
{
    g.setColor(Color.blue);   // <--- null pointer exception
    g.fillOval(xy.x, xy.y, 5, 5);
}

}
```

and the main class:

```
package gui;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    new Gui().draw(new Tuple(200,200)); //Tuple is a custom class I wrote

}
}
```

Comment: Don’t maintain a reference to Graphics, instead, use a setter to set the Tuple value (and call repaint) and then from within paintComponent, paint the Tuple if it’s not null

Comment: And how do I make the paintComponent method run again to check if the Tuple has updated?

Comment: Call repaint ...

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to my null problem. I modified the method "draw()" to accept a tuple and then pass it into the paintComponent() function and call repaint().

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel{

    Graphics g;
    Tuple xy;

    public Gui() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.g = g;

        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        for(int x = 0;x < 700; x += 20) 
        {
            g.drawLine(x, 0, x, 700);
        }

        for(int y = 0;y < 700; y += 20) 
        {
            g.drawLine(0, y, 700, y);
        }

        if(xy != null) 
        {
            g.fillOval(xy.x, xy.y, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Tuple xy)
    {
        this.xy = xy;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you should do all the drawing on the

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

method as is stated on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html.

Answer (score -1):

Use a callback function.  Much better than `polling` the property.  And you get a fresh graphics object.  And your call is executed in the proper context.

Here is the general idea:

## Instantiation

```
new Gui((Graphics graphics)-> {
   // your code here
});
```

## CTOR or Init function

```
public Gui(GraphicsCallback callback)
```

## Invoke

Invoke the callback.  You can check if invoked and only callback once if it suits your use case.  Or the callback implementation can manage getting called muliple times.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.g = g;
    this.callback(g)
```